# SASS / SCSS: Read file names in a directory

Tags: css, function, sass

i want to list all *.svg files in a directory, something like this:

```
// set the folder containing *.svg
$icon-dir: "./my-icon-collection";

// then produces a css like this:
.icon {
   .face {
      background-image: url("face.svg");
   }
   .phone{
      background-image: url("phone.svg");
   }
   .message-miss{
      background-image: url("message-miss.svg");
   }
}
```

how i write the function/mixin in SASS/SCSS?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this achievable in a generated css via scss. At the nearest solution is you can get css like this-
[generated css image by the below mentioned mixin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkR86.png)

```
   $svg-list:"perimter","surface","length","height","width","volume","area"; 
$icon-dir: "./my-icon-collection/"; // Assuming this is the correct location where all the svg files are placed
@mixin svgPath($svgName) {
    .icon {
    .#{$svgName} {
        background-image: url(#{$icon-dir}#{$svgName}.svg);
    }
    }
}
@each $svgName in $svg-list {
    @include svgPath($svgName);
}
```